# Unexpected newlines on output Powershell write to file

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

OK, so admit I'm a newb in PS, and crafting a script by cobbling together a command or two taken from various places.

I am reading the registry to get a list of installed fonts on a user's machine. (It's only done once, when user first runs program, and a file is written out)

```
if (!(Test-Path $ScriptDir/fnt_files/psFonts.js)){
$reg = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
Out-File $ScriptDir/fnt_files/psFonts.txt -InputObject $reg -Encoding unicode
```

}

But the result is a little weird ...

```
Arial (TrueType)                                                                                            : a
                                                                                                              r
                                                                                                              i
                                                                                                              a
                                                                                                              l
                                                                                                              .
                                                                                                              t
                                                                                                              t
                                                                                                              f
Arial Black (TrueType)                                                                                      : a
                                                                                                              r
                                                                                                              i
                                                                                                              b
                                                                                                              l
                                                                                                              k
                                                                                                              .
                                                                                                              t
                                                                                                              t
                                                                                                              f
```

ie the first part is correct, but after the hyphen, the words are spaced out placing one letter per line. I've tried ASCII and Unicode, but neither have any effect.

Having just checked the hex, it seems it is worse than I thought. After the first letter is "ODOA" ... followed by 111 "20", next letter "ODOA" 111 spaces (???)

**Coincidentally, the output is TOTALLY different to the same command in CMD, and creates an ENTIRELY DIFFERENT set of fonts??**

This has got me totally baffled!

UPDATE: Someone asked me to add the CMD version I'm running:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /s > ../fnt_files/FontList.txt"
```

(Having checked, the CSV script listed below picks up fonts that are not even shown in REGEDIT ... and yet STILL returns 100 fonts LESS that the above CMD that takes the list of files directly from REGEDIT!! OK, so 400 fonts are more than enough for my project, but =NOW= I'm just curious as to what's going on!)

UPDATE2: Oh dear! Egg on face time! The one that showed more fonts was generated by Win7. But I have just upgraded to Win10, so the font structure has been changed!!

Comment: when it prints that reg key, it is a table and by default the width is too small. Try `$reg = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" | Out-file $ScriptDir/fnt_files/psFonts.txt -Width 10000`

Comment: your code works for me ... the list is long [465 items] and includes the `PS*` stuff that PoSh adds, but it lists out neatly on screen, in the file when viewed with NP++, and on screen when loaded with `Get-Content`. you didn't list the CMD version, so i cannot test that.

Comment: Lee Dailey. I've just updated to Win10, and using the ISE that comes with it. The CMD version was written by the version using Win7.

Comment: Nazard. That's getting there. All on one line, but now I have "00" between each code (as well as the spaces) But - from doing things in the past - I'm fairly sure that can be fixed by using the correct encoding - maybe UTF8 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Out-File` can give you width/wordwrap issues, `Export-Csv` is easier to work with.

```
if (!(Test-Path $ScriptDir/fnt_files/psFonts.js)){
    $reg = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
    $data = $reg.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" -and $_.Value -match "\..{3}$"}) | Select-Object Name, Value
    $data | Export-Csv -Path $ScriptDir/fnt_files/psFonts.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I've made the assumption all your fonts have a 3 character extension.

Comment: jfrmilner. Not tried that code yet ... but CSV would be A LOT easier to work with. When I used the CMD version, it output three sections with (REG_SZ) in the middle with spaces either side. So I coded JS to filter out the 1st and 3rd field (family name and file name) This JS is then output to create a browser app that displays font name and words in that font.

Comment: In the question, I said it output different fonts. What I forgot was that CMD version included a filter to sort the results aplhabetically ... something else to add to the code once I've got the file writing correctly!

Comment: Just looked at that CSV code. I wouldn't have come up with that code in many a week !! So thanks.

Comment: jfrmilner: Lovely, works great. Now I'm curious as to why the command from CMD output 547 fonts, but this version gave 459 ! I'll have to go each file to find out what's missing, and then try to work out why! (Then I code - JS - to weed out "otf" which won't display in browser, and "ttc" which I presume are chinese

Comment: @ChrisBrown Could you please add the command you're using with cmd to your question?

Comment: OH DEAR !! Embarrasing!! My original text file was generated pre-Win7toWin10 upgrade ... and the latter has created a different set of fonts!! Ran CMD now, and got same results !!

Comment: @ChrisBrown In a way, good news! Please have a look at https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers and accept this answer.

Comment: Ticked as accepted, but cannot vote as need to log in for that rather than as "Guest" ... but the log in account is 'locked', and don't want to risk not being able to post again.